# How to get a list of placeholders / variables in a word template

Tags: templates, placeholder, phpword

using phpword, I would like to get a list of all the placeholders ${var_name} that is in a template

I have searched here and in the documentation but I have not been able to find a function that can give a list of placeholders / variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're referring to the PHPWord [TemplateProcessor](https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templates-processing.html).It actually does provide a method that returns an array of all the variables in the template, which is `$phpWord->getVariables()` as refer to the [source code](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/master/src/PhpWord/TemplateProcessor.php#L709). I found it when digging into the source code. The official [documentation](https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) is long out of date.

Hope it helps!